# Ionic app works true on browser but does not work fine in my android device

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have developed an ionic application which it works fine in chrome but after generating .apk file it does not work fine. there is only a warning in chrome developer mode :

```
SVG's SMIL animations (<animate>, <set>, etc.) are deprecated and will be removed. Please use CSS animations or Web animations instead.
```

Here are the details :

1. I am using only ng-cordova plugin and maps.google .
2. I use typescript
3. I have used http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html for generating .apk .

After installing the application on android device, it runs but it only shows my parrent view :

I have an index.html file which is my parent view :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>


    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=My_Api_Kei"></script>

    <script src="my_apps_js"></script> </head>

<body dir="rtl" ng-app="appName">
    <ion-nav-view animation="slide-right-left"></ion-nav-view> </body> </html>
```

This is my run and config functions :

```
    export var ehmcoModule = angular.module('ModuleName', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']); 

  ehmcoModule.run(function($ionicPlatform: ionic.platform.IonicPlatformService) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

      if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
      }
       if (window.StatusBar) {
          //org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
         StatusBar.styleDefault();
       }
    });   });

  ehmcoModule.config(function($stateProvider: ng.ui.IStateProvider, $urlRouterProvider: ng.ui.IUrlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('app', {
        url: '/app',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
        controller: Controllers.EhmcoController.controllerName
      })
      .state('app.home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
            controller:Controllers.HomeController.controllerName
          }
        }
      })
      .state('app.category', {
            url: '/category',
            views: {
                'menuContent': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/category.html',
                    controller:Controllers.CategoryController.controllerName
                }
            }
      })


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');   });
```

I don't think that this is a routing problem because I add an item to menu in parent view and route it to first page (app/home). It goes there but angular library does not load there and binded value does not show.

Comment: Did you try, just to run `ionic run android --device`? Don't start with the release build, try to do a debug build first.

Comment: yes i have tried it. the application start in the same state which i describe above.

Comment: this is a good article on such a problems (but it does not solve my problem): http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-debug-the-white-screen-of-death-in-your-ionic-app/

Comment: Start `\Android\android-sdk\tools\monitor.bat`. With that tool you were be able to get the console output of your device. Hope, this gives you some hint...

Comment: by using usb debuging and running command : ionic run android -l -c application work fine in my table but there is the same problem in installed app using apk !!

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solve the problem.
i am using typescript and there was some problem in injection in controllers. it works fine in browser but after generating apk file it does not work fine.
in order to find such a problem first we can use 'ng-strict-di' directive:

```
 <body dir="rtl" ng-app="Ehmco" ng-strict-di>
    <ion-nav-view animation="slide-right-left"></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
```

besides of that after activating usb debugging mode of our device, we can run our application by command :

```
ionic run --device
```

or

```
ionic cordova run --device android
ionic cordova run --device ios
```

then in

```
chrome://inspect/#devices
```

we can debug our application and view the problems.